# How to include a .vbs script file into a .xhtml file?

Tags: xhtml, vbscript

How do I include a .vbs file into a .xhtml file?

Comment: As in, do you want to run a given vbs script on a client's computer using perhaps ActiveX?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<script>` tag to include the VBS in your page like this:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
  // your VBS code
</script>
```

***Note***  that VBS only runs in IE. You need to go for **[JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)** to get your script run in all browsers.

Comment: thank you so much for the response, one more quick question...can I have the script in a .vbs file and then can I import into the .xhtml file...

Comment: @user303451: I don't think so and you shouldn't when you can insert script directly in the page :)